# Import android project in Intellij IDEA/use shared resources

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-resources

I have an android project in eclipse with the following structure:

```
|Project1
   |-src
   |-res

|Project2
   |-src
   |-res
```

Project2 link to source and resource of the Project1. *(In Eclipse: Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Link Source).*

I try to import the project in the IDEA with the same structure (project will be used in the Eclipse and IDEA at a time). When importing, i encountered the following problems:

**1. If i add Project1 in Dependencies for Project2 (Project Structure -> Dependencies), i receive the error when trying to run Project2:**

> android-apt-compiler: ...\AndroidManifest.xml:45: error: Error: Noresource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value'@drawable/ic_launcher')
>
> android-apt-compiler: ...\AndroidManifest.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name')
>
> ...

But in code (Project2) i can refer to resources from Project1 without any errors.

**2. Then i tried to set in Project2 path to resources directory of Project1 (Project Structure -> Facet 'Android' -> Structure), and receive error:**

> android-apt-compiler: ...\res\values\dimens.xml:7: error: Resource entry activity_vertical_margin is already defined.
>
> android-apt-compiler: ...\res\values\strings.xml:1412: error: Resource entry device_not_found is already defined.
>
> ...

**3. I also tried to add res and src folder as a content root (Project Structure -> Sources), and receive notification:**

Module Project1 must not contain source root "...\Project1\src".
The root already belongs to module "Project2".

**4. And i tried set same parametres as in step 1 and additionaly make Project1 as library (Project Structure -> Facet 'Android' -> Library module). I receive errors for Project1:**

> java:...\Project1\src\com...\TimeLineFragment.java:276: constant
>   expression required
>   java:...\Project1\src\com...\TimeLineFragment.java:276: constant
>   expression required

for code like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_open_dial_pad:
        mDialPadListener.openDialpad();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_delete_all:
        mObserver.onDeleteAllEventsAction();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have no more ideas how to import a project in IDEA. Is there any solution how to do this (for the described project structure), so in Eclipse all work fine?

Answer (score 2):

The **error 3** can be corrected just by going to the **Artifacts Settings, Modules, Sources tab,** and you will see 2 folders called "gen" and "gen[generated]", **delete "gen"** by clicking on the X icon to the right of it.

Now, to use both "projects", you need to understand that what in Eclipse is a "Project" would be equivalent to what a "module" is in Intellij, so all you need to do is **open one project, and then "Import Module"**, so you select the other "Project", this way they will be able to see each other resources and codes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to modules -> set SDK as Android studio's sdk (the sdk that came with Android Strudio's bundle, or any other SDK tht
2. In Dependencies set SDK as project SDK